# Can someone explain me these "sed" commands and what they are doing?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

Can someone give me a quick explanation what these lines are doing and what they effects are?

1) `sed -i "/^exampleusername/s/:1000:1000:/:${UID}:${GID}:/g" /etc/passwd`

2) `sed -i "/^examplegroupname/s/:1000:/:${GID}:/g" /etc/group`

I saw them [here](https://github.com/itzg/dockerfiles/blob/2627317e03617fbe4de424e2effcd63df9798a46/minecraft-server/start#L4) if you are interested in more context.

Comment: Hello, have you tried reading `sed`'s manual page? It describes its language well

Comment: Yes, but I also don't quiet understand what kind of permissions or something are added due to these commands

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out a sed tutorial or man page. Here is #1 broken down (and no longer valid `sed`). The second one has the same general form:

```
/^exampleusername/      # Perform a command on matching lines (address)
    s/                  # Substitute command with / as delimiter
      :1000:1000:       # Pattern to find
      /                 # Delimiter
      :${UID}:${GID}:   # String to replace with (expanded by bash)
      /                 # Terminating delimiter
      g                 # Regex flag (global: replace all matches in line)
```

So it just finds the line that starts with `exampleusername` and replaces all occurrences of `:1000:1000:` with your current user's UID/GID.

This effectively makes `exampleusername` the same as your current user.

Comment: You might mention, that /g doesn't make much sense here, and that it therefor looks, as if some cargo-cult-programmer wrote that code, adapting it without knowing exactly, what he is doing.

Comment: If this was a code review, it would indeed be worth mentioning that plus prefix matching the username, assuming an existing uid/gid, using variables that don't exist in sh, and not just using a tool like `usermod`.

Comment: In the context of the linked `Dockerfile` they ensure that the user account in the Docker image has the same UID and GID as yourself on the host system where you are building the image.

Comment: FYI for context, the passwd file hacking was necessary since Alpine doesn't have a `usermod` command.

Comment: ...and commented and removed g flags here https://github.com/itzg/dockerfiles/blob/e2bf56938b391c1143939815350336c94372c0d0/minecraft-server/start#L4-L6